# Safe access to multithreaded HashMap Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an application which has a ConcurrentHashMap which locally stores a copy of data stored on an external server. The map is updated every few seconds with a new copy of the data.

I have a loop that runs every few seconds which has access to the HashMap and adds the elements to an array in the order of values (it actually does quite a bit more but that is irrelevant). My problem is that if the data changes while it is in the middle of creating the array you could have duplicated keys in different places or leave some out entirely.

Example:

```
// Map starts out like this
1 -> value1
2 -> value2
3 -> value3
4 -> value4

// First 2 elements of array created
value1,value2

// Map is updated
3 -> value3
1 -> value1
2 -> value2
4 -> value4

// Last 2 elements of array created
value1,value2,value1,value4
```

As you can see if the map had not been changed the array would be: "value1,value2,value3,value4" or "value2,value3,value1,value4" if it had been run after the update.

Here is some example code, it is not the original but it should explain my problem:

```
Map<Integer, String> mapThatGetsUpdated = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>();
String[] array = new String[mapThatGetsUpdated.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < mapThatGetsUpdated.size(); i++) {
    array[i] = mapThatGetsUpdated.get(i);
}
```

The obvious way to do this is to copy the map then discard it after use but I would like another way as the map could be quite large and it would have to be copied possibly several times a second.

Comment: Could you just lock (synchronize on) the hashmap while updating or reading it?

Comment: HashMap doesn't maintain the insertion order.

Comment: @Braj Edited the post to make it a bit more clear, I am using the key for the index in array.

Comment: @immibis methinks that might defeat the purpose of a `ConcurrentHashMap` a wee bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem because although `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread safe, you are carrying out compound operations without locking.

**If you want to guarantee consistent state you must prevent writing while reading.**

If you want a reader to see the same information for the entire read operation then you must;

- either prevent writing during the read
- create a snapshot of the entity being read at the start

**Option 1** (Don't do this)

Lock the `Map` with `synchronized` during the reading and writing, allowing on one to occur at a time.

This is the first recourse of many a rookie programmer. It will effectively remove any benefit from having the `ConcurrentHashMap`.

**Option 2** (Don't do this)

Copy the `Map` before reading from it.

Noting that the iteration might be doing something other that just looping, you try and minimise the lock on reading by only copying the map in the `synchronized` block and using the copy.

Because you are reading rather regularly, this will most likely not help either.

**Option 3**

Use an `AtomicReference`. Copy the reference in the reader to a local reference. The writer replaces the reference by a completely new `Map`.

The feasibility of this option depends on how much writing is happening. It is called [Copy on Write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) and can lead to good throughput if writes are few and reads are many.

It doesn't require explicit locking, but does require writers to do a lot more work.

**Option 4**

Use a [`ReentrantReadWriteLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). Change the `Map` to a `HashMap` and control the concurrency yourself (write a wrapper class).

Use the `ReadLock` to lock reads and the `WriteLock` to lock writes. You can have many readers but only one writer at a time.

The will guarantee consistent reads.